# public static final int rd_!=0x7f08000f; generated automatically

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

I don't understand why this line is created in the gen id file : `public static final int rd_!=0x7f08000f;` and is giving me an error `Syntax error on token "!=", = expected`
I tried cleaning the project with no success...

anone has an idea?

Comment: When appeared the first time??, can you post the layouts??

Comment: well the layout is quite long.... but what could cause such an error?

Comment: are you sure you're not using "!" in any id of the layout??

Comment: no I just checked, I just tried to delete the line and restart eclipse but the line comes back.

Comment: Then do what @Sushil suggested

Comment: Well I was looking only in the main layout (oups) so it was a radio button named rd_! (code downloaded from internet...) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a radio button named rd_! in the secondary layout that was causing the problem. just renamed it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just check in your folder. There could have been some temporary xml file or some other file has been generated by system which is causing this issue. Just delete that file. It should work

Comment: @zopa Do a search like * .xml for files containing the text rd *, or check if that line exists